Bash - Get certain parameters from a command and put them in a string
I want to:

get all the parameters from a command but the first two ones
create a string with the result of previous step

So if I have this command:
mycommand param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 paramN

I should end up with this literal string:
"param3 param4 param5 paramN"

I know that to get the all params but the first two I can:
echo "'${@:3}'"

And to put all the params into a string I can:
echo "'$*'"

But I don't know how to combine these two approaches to achieve what I want.

a) did you try the obvious echo "'${*:3}'" and, if so, in what way did that not do what you want? b) echo "'${@:3}'" will already output a string so in what way is that not sufficient for your needs? I feel like what you're really trying to do isn't captured in the question yet.

In bash, like in ksh93 where bash copied that syntax from, just use "${*:3}" (don't omit the quotes) after having set $IFS to the joining character you want:
mycommand() {
  local IFS=' ' # the first character of $IFS is used for "$*" joining
  printf 'Third to last, joined with spaces: "%s"\n' "${*:3}"
}

bash-5.2$ mycommand param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 paramN
Third to last, joined with spaces: "param3 param4 param5 paramN"

It would work in recent versions of zsh as well, but there you'd rather use ${(j[ ])@[3,-1]} where you can specify how elements are to be joined explicitly without having to modify a global parameter, and using $array[first,last] syntax rather than ksh93's ${array[*]:offset:length} which conflicts with csh modifiers and Bourne's ${var:-value} (but that zsh eventually ended up supporting with restrictions decades later for compatibility with ksh93/bash).

This can be done via shift command:
# cat a.sh
shift 2; echo "$*"

or
shift; shift ; echo "$*"  

The second give expected result when the number of parameters is less than 2   (on my bash v4.4.12)
# ./a.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6

To put them in variable:
shift 2; a="$*"

or
shift ; shift; a="$*"

(see above)

@Kusalananda, beware that shift 2 is not the same thing as shift;shift when $# is 1. The behaviour of the bash shell in that regard is affected by its posix option. Using shift "$(($# < 2 ? $# : 2))" would be preferable here to avoid the error messages in posix mode when $# < 2.

@StéphaneChazelas, you are right, added two options :)
